# Laravel code Issue

Tags: php, html, laravel

Someone Help me for convert html code into laravel

```
HTML code look like
<td><button class="btn red" type="button"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Delete</button></td>
i am try following but it is not work properly
{{HTML::linkRoute('users.edit','Edit',$value->id,['class'=>'btn green'])}}
```

Comment: plain html nice work in laravel

Comment: but i want to use route so plain html do not enough

Comment: your html without rout, and we don't know what rout you want to get

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting a button use the following;

```
{{ Form::button('Edit', array('type' => 'button', 'class' => 'btn green', 'onclick' => 'window.location="' . route('users.edit', $value->id) . '"')); }}
```

Comment: @HarsukhMakwana Not that excellent if you keep changing the answer

Comment: i like your answer so happy brother

Answer (score 0):

this may work for you

```
{{ link_to_route('users.edit', 'Edit',$value->id,array('class' => 'btn green')) }}
```